# UML Composition vs SQL Foreign Key

Tags: domain-driven-design, uml

Does the following image (i.e. a non-navigable composition relation) makes sense in an early-stage UML class diagram of a Domain Model?

[image: class]

I want to express that it will not be possible to do `Company.Accounts`, but that if the Company object is destroyed, all Accounts are to be destroyed too. My motivations are to avoid the `Company` class to become some kind of God-Object anti-pattern as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896848/how-to-avoid-having-very-large-objects-with-domain-driven-design). In DB terms: there's a foreign key from `Account --> Company`. In the actual app, just about everything will be owned by the Company and, for performance reason, I don't want to allow lazy/eager loading all the child collections from the Company.

I imagine the final diagram would probably have an `IAccountRepository` (see following image) but I find that it burdens the Class Diagram to put everything there. Imagine adding the extra *infrastructure* classes for each child collection. The class diagram would become unreadable!

[image: class diagram2]

How do you convey the **idea** in the Domain Model that loading is going to be "indirect"? Does it even go there?

Any references or industry standard on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing behavioral modeling with static model. The relation you set between `Company` and `Account` is OK if `Company` **never** accesses `Account` directly, but if you have functions in `Company` that access `Account`, then your model is wrong.

From what I know, there is no way to model that on the one side `Company` is composed of `Accounts` but that the accounts are actually stored in another place. Your second diagram is not correct, because if `Company` is composed of `Accounts`, then `IAccountRepository` should access them through `Company` and not directly.

IMHO, `Account` should have composition from `IAccountRepository` to `Account`, association from `Company` to `Account`, and in a sequence diagram of `ICompanyRepository.deleteCompany` that when a company is deleted, all of it's accounts are deleted.

Comment: Thanks. What I was trying to convey by the repositories is that the application will be able to load both `Company` and `Account` directly. Accounts belong to a Company, it's a NOT NULL Foreign Key constraint in the database, but I do not want to access them through the company everytime I need Account ID ABC... I'm sure I understand what you mean by "Account should have composition from IAccountRepository to Account", `IAccountRepository` is not the owner of `Account`, no?

Comment: It is problematic to show what you want in a class diagram. The only option I see is to remove the `X` in the composition link you have and adding a comment to this link saying that the accounts are fetched from the `IAccountRepository` and not directly from the `Company`